# Using JUnit, Maven and Hudson/Jenkins for integration tests

Tags: junit, hudson, integration-testing

We are going to use `Hudson/Jenkins` build server to both build our server applications (just calling `maven`) and run integration tests against it. We are going to prepare 3 `Hudson/Jenkins` jobs: for build, deploy and run integration tests, which call each other in this order. All these jobs (build, deploy, integration tests) will be running nightly.

The integration tests are written with `JUnit` and are invoked by `mvn test`, (which will be invoked by the "test" `Hudson/Jenkins` job in turn). Since they require the server to be up and running we have to run that "deploy" job.

Does it make sense? Is there are any special server to deploy application and run tests or `Hudson/Jenkins` is ok for that?

Comment: Why are you using three different jobs? What kind of servers are you using ? (What kind of application?)

Answer (score 6):

It definitely makes sense, basically you are referring to a build pipeline. There is a [Jenkins-plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin) to help visualize the upstream/downstream projects (you create a new pipeline view in jenkins).

As for the deployment of the server component, this depends on what technology/stack you are running on. For instance you could write a script that deploys the application to a test environment using a post-build step in jenkins.

Another option is to use a maven plugin to deploy the application. You can separate the deployment step in profile, and run only the deploy goal on the deploy step etc.

Basically there are a lot of options, but the idea of a build pipeline makes a lot of sense. To read up on build pipelines and related topics I would suggest taking a look at [Continuous Deployment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321601912).

For more information related to Jenkins, have a look at [this video](http://vimeo.com/24691568).

> Does it make sense? Is there are any special server to deploy
>   application and run tests or Hudson/Jenkins is ok for that?

You can run the application on the same server as jenkins, but wether that makes sense depends on the application. If it depends heavily on a specific server setup, a better choice may be to run the server in a vm, and but the configuration in source control. There are plenty of tools to help automate this, of the top of my head you have [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/), [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) and [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the technology of your server, you could do all of this in a single Hudson project, executing your integration tests using Maven's [Failsafe plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/) instead of Surefire.

This allows you to start and deploy prior to executing the integration tests, and shutdown your server after they have completed. It also allows you to separate your integration tests from your unit tests.

For Java EE applications, you can perform the start/deploy/stop steps using [Cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin), or use an embedded Jetty containing and the [Jetty Maven plugin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin).